# How to add one or more points to an existing polyline or polygon?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

Using the following code, I make a polyline with two points.

```
  vl = QgsVectorLayer("LineString", layerName, "memory")
  pr = vl.dataProvider()
  vl.startEditing()
  fet = QgsFeature()
  fet.setGeometry( QgsGeometry.fromPolyline( [QgsPoint(x1,y1), QgsPoint(x2,y2)] ))
  pr.addFeatures( [ fet ] )
```

What I want is to add a line to this polyline while I keep only one id. So I can not use:

```
  fet.setGeometry( QgsGeometry.fromPolyline( [QgsPoint(x3,y3), QgsPoint(x4,y4)] ))
```

because this will save two lines with two different id's.

I can see in the QGIS API that there is a command:

```
    addPart (const QList< QgsPoint > &points)
    Adds a new island polygon to a multipolygon feature.
```

but I do not know if it works or how to use it. Does anybody have any idea how to add points or several points to an existing polygon or polyline?

Answer (score 2):

I made it work by using these lines of code:

```
geom = fet.geometry()
geom.insertVertex(x4,y4,len(geom.asPolyline()))
fet.setGeometry(geom)
```

Comment: You're asking a lot of questions about PyQGIS-bindings. To make your answers useable/searchable for other users try to (1) accept correct answers, (2) apply the correct tags and a descriptive headline